# Kernel and Pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the expression below.

\begin{equation}
B \, \mu = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mu^+ \, B^+ = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mu^{\intercal} \, B^+
\end{equation}

Could you enlight me on its proof by linear algebra steps. On above expression, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: Please elaborate on what $B$ and $\mu$ are.

Comment: I edited the expression for better comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty boring proof. Since $B^+B$ and $BB^+$ are real symmetric,
\begin{aligned}
\color{red}{B\mu=0}
&\Rightarrow B^+B\mu=0\\
&\Rightarrow \mu^TB^+B=\left((B^+B)^T\mu\right)^T=\left(B^+B\mu\right)^T=0\\
&\Rightarrow \mu^TB^+BB^+=0\\
&\Rightarrow\color{red}{\mu^TB^+=0}\\
&\Rightarrow\mu^TB^+B=0\\
&\Rightarrow B^+B\mu=(B^+B)^T\mu=(\mu^TB^+B)^T=0\\
&\Rightarrow BB^+B\mu=0\\
&\Rightarrow\color{red}{B\mu=0}.
\end{aligned}
Hence $B\mu=0$ is equivalent to $\mu^TB^+=0$. The latter is also equivalent to $\mu^+B^+=0$ because $\mu^+=(\mu^T\mu)^+\mu^T$.

For a more interesting proof, consider the geometric meanings of $B\mu=0$ and $\mu^TB^+=0$.

Comment: I do not comprehend the equivalency $\mu^+ B$ to $\mu^T B^+$

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto If $\mu=0$, both $\mu^TB^+$ and $\mu^+B^+$ are zero. If $\mu$ is nonzero, then $\mu^+=(\mu^T\mu)^{-1}\mu^T$. Therefore $\mu^+B^+=0\Leftrightarrow (\mu^T\mu)^{-1}\mu^TB^+=0\Leftrightarrow\mu^TB^+=0$.